# Center Frame in Main Window - Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, frame, tkinter-layout

How can I achieve a result like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjYDX.png) in python Tkinter?
I want a window with a main frame whose width takes up 50% of the window's width and, if need be, two side frames of 25% width each.

Here's the simplified code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")

f1 = Frame(root,bg="white",width=root.winfo_width()//4)
f1.pack()
main = Frame(root,bg="black",width=root.winfo_width()//2)
main.pack()
f2 = Frame(root,bg="white",width=root.winfo_width()//4)
f2.pack()
```

Why are the frames not showing? Please help!

> **Bonus point** if you can do away with the two side frames

Answer (score 3):

It can be achieved by using `.place()`:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry("100x100")

main = Frame(root,bg="black")
main.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, relwidth=0.5, relheight=1, anchor="c")

root.mainloop()
```